# ReferenceError: Can't find variable: action in React native expo project

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo

This errror message shown when trying to run reactnative app using expo

> ReferenceError: Can't find variable: action
> at node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Core/ExceptionsManager.js:104:6 in reportException
> at node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Core/ExceptionsManager.js:171:19 in handleException
> at node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Core/setUpErrorHandling.js:24:6 in handleError
> at node_modules/expo-error-recovery/build/ErrorRecovery.fx.js:12:21 in ErrorUtils.setGlobalHandler$argument_0
> at [native code]:null in flushedQueue
> at [native code]:null in invokeCallbackAndReturnFlushedQueue

Unable to start your application. Please refer to https://expo.fyi/no-registered-application for more information.
at node_modules/react-native/Libraries/ReactNative/AppRegistry.js:200:6 in runApplication
at [native code]:null in callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue

I think this issue is related to reactnative and not my project.

Comment: Hey @Jokanola did you find the solution?

Comment: No, I find a workaround.

Comment: What was the workaround? @Jokanola